# Why won't my links align to the right as well as display spaces in between social icons?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to move the links to the right and I want the social icons that are already on the right to have some reasonable space in between them using bootstrap, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

My attempt below isn't working and I don't know why (the image below is what I'm currently seeing).

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

[image]

```
import React from 'react';

const header = () => {
    return(
        <header>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">

                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
                        aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse text-xs-right" id="navbarCollapse">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item active">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Winners <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Sweepstakes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link disabled" href="#">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link disabled" href="#">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div className="text-xs-right">
                    <a href="#" className="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                    <a href="#" className="fa fa-instagram"></a>
                    <a href="#" className="fa fa-youtube"></a>
                    <a href="#" className="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    );
};

export default header;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the predefined `btn` class to achieve the desired spacing. Also, consider adding `btn-small` to achieve a spacing/padding amount that is more suited to these social network buttons, and `btn-link` to retain the look and feel of the social network buttons:

```
<div className="text-xs-right">
  <a href="#" className="btn btn-small btn-link fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" className="btn btn-small btn-link fa fa-instagram"></a>
  <a href="#" className="btn btn-small btn-link fa fa-youtube"></a>
  <a href="#" className="btn btn-small btn-link fa fa-twitter"></a>
</div>
```

For more information on the `btn` button class, and button modifier classes like `btn-small` and `btn-link`, [see the documentation for buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/)

Comment: ah ok, I got you.  But with this suggestion, I'm losing the color that's associated with the social icon.  They aren't blue anymore like it's shown on the screenshot I provided.

Comment: @greyskies ah ok - just updated answer. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.mx-1` to your icons to make each of them margin left and right:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="text-xs-right">
    <a href="#" class="mx-1 fa fa-facebook-f"></a>
    <a href="#" class="mx-1 fa fa-instagram"></a>
    <a href="#" class="mx-1 fa fa-youtube"></a>
    <a href="#" class="mx-1 fa fa-twitter"></a>
</div>
```